# Looking for a name for programming technique

Tags: javascript, loops, object, lookup, state-machine

Imagine you have a Object in JavaScript that holds state transitions and returns next state of the state you passed in. Something like this:

```
const stateLooper = {
  state1: 'state2',
  state2: 'state3',
  state3: 'state1',
}
```

What is this type of "machine" officially called ? I can't find anything on the web. Does anybody know ?

Comment: finite state machine ...?

Comment: A lookup table, or a dictionary?

Comment: They look like completion transitions to me